# Azure mobile services-invokeApi

Tags: android, azure

In my android app, im using azure mobile sdk to access , azure services. Now i need to separate this thing to two layers. UI and the service layer. 
Since im using invokeAPI and onComplete overriden mothod, how do i retrun object or collection from service layer?

```
azClient.invokeApi("getuserorderhistory", new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonResponse, Exception exception,
                ServiceFilterResponse response) {
```